# Can I change tinymce behavior of wrapping text with semantic tags such as <strong> or <em>?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg, semantic-markup

guys.

I need some helps about tinymce.

I'd like to do as like below with tinymce. (I want to do)

```
<strong>Entire words are bold.</strong>
<strong><em>But this is italic.</em></strong>
<strong>I'm still bold!</strong>
```

However, while I have done with tinymce, I'm getting

```
<strong>Entire words are bold.
<em>But this is italic.</em>
I'm still bold!</strong>
```

This would be happen when making all text bold, and then make part of text italic.

Here are what I tried to set

```
style_formats: [{title: 'Bold text', inline: 'strong'},
                {title: 'Italic text', inline: 'em'}]
```

or

```
formats: {
    bold: {inline: 'strong'},
    italic: {inline: 'em'}
}
```

and so on...

Is there any option or hack to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but is this the course of action you're taking to bold/italicize your content?

1. Highlight all text.
2. Press the `bold` button.
3. Highlight the second line.
4. Press the `italic` button.

The default behaviour should be that each line is wrapped in its own `<strong>` tag. You might want to check if you have Style Merging enabled - this may be causing what you're experiencing.

Comment: First of all, I appreciate your answer. Yes, I had taken the course that you mentioned. However I have checked if style_formats_merge was set to true or not, it didn't work as I expected. Then, I had a work from different side(back-end) using HTML parser(JSoup), because what I wanted to do finally was parsing that html and apply styles to excel using apache poi library. So, this issue is no longer problem to me, and so far it was actually symantic. Anyway, thanks again.